# Plone traversing and forbidden Zope ids

Tags: plone, zope

Although you can generate by code contents with an id that starts with **underscore**, like "`_foo`" it seems that you can't traverse an item with this special id.
Every attempt to access a content named that way **using a browser** lead to a *NotFound* error. Neither methods like `__bobotraverse__` or `__getitem__` are called, like if this limitation is checked very early.

How this limitation works and how can I change it? Can I access subobjects with a prefix underscore in the id?

Comment: AFAIK it's implemented as beforetraversel hook. But I'm not sure where they burry the code :-) I'll add an answer when I dug enough deep.

Comment: Clarify what kind of traversal you mean?  Object publishing via HTTPRequest or something like unrestrictedTraverse()?

Comment: I simply need to acces through browser an URL like http://myplonesite/myfoldercontent/_something

Comment: hmmm... probably this  may help you: https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.publisher/blob/master/src/zope/publisher/base.py#L438. But it raises Unauthorized not NotFound.

Comment: @Mathias it really raise a NotFound. I see some reference to this there: http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/book/chap3.html#c37ac15c11b4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found inside the `unrestrictedTraverse` implementation from `OFS.Traversable`:

```
if name[0] == '_':
    # Never allowed in a URL.
    raise NotFound, name
```

...but this is not enough. There's another check similar to the ones notified by @Mathias inside `ZPublisher.BaseRequest.DefaultPublishTraverse` in the `publishTraverse` method.

```
if name[:1]=='_':
    raise Forbidden("Object name begins with an underscore at: %s" % URL)
```

The sad part is that is not simple to override this:

- the `unrestrictedTraverse` is called on the Plone site context (so I can't customize it only for my content type)
- the `publishTraverse` method is owned by the request implementation (maybe for this I can use ad custom publish traverser?)

The simplest way to fix this seems through monkeypatch.

Comment: this is part of the [Default Zope Security Policy](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/Security.html#details-of-the-default-zope-security-policy): *access to an object whose name begins with the underscore character ‘_’ is always denied*, and reminds [PEP 8 Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) where a trailing underscore indicates internal use.